# Send more than one instance of an object over UDP

Tags: java, object, network-programming, udp

I'm new to `java network programming`.
I try to send more than one instance of an `object` named Packet over UDP.
Sender: changes String to charArray, then sends each char in an `object`.
Receiver: receives the Datagrampacket and readObject then prints it out.
Sender is ok, but the receiver just takes the first instance of the object, and prints it as many times as the length of the charArray. Here is my code:
Receiver

```
public class Receiver {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    { 
        DatagramSocket rcvSocket;
        DatagramPacket rcvPacket;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;
        byte[] rcvData;
        Packet SnWPacket;

        rcvSocket = new DatagramSocket(7777);
        rcvData = new byte[1024];
        rcvPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvData, rcvData.length);

        while(true)
        {
            rcvSocket.receive(rcvPacket);
            byte[] in = rcvPacket.getData();
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            SnWPacket = (Packet) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("RECIEVED: " + SnWPacket);
            ois.close();
            bis.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Sender

```
public class Sender {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    { 

        DatagramPacket sndPacket;
        DatagramSocket sndSocket;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        InetAddress addr;
        Scanner sc;

        char[] charArray;
        int seqNo = 0;
        byte sndData[];
        Packet SnWPacket;

        addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        sndSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input: ");
        String in = sc.nextLine();
        charArray = in.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            SnWPacket = new Packet("data", seqNo, charArray[i]);
            oos.writeObject(SnWPacket);
            oos.flush();
            sndData = bos.toByteArray();
            bos.flush();
            sndPacket = new DatagramPacket(sndData, sndData.length, addr, 7777);
            sndSocket.send(sndPacket);
            System.out.println("SENT: " + SnWPacket);
            seqNo += 1;
        }
        oos.close();
        bos.close();
        sndSocket.close();
    } 
}
```

Packet

```
public class Packet implements Serializable{
    private String type;
    private int seqNo;
    private char data;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public int getSeqNo() {
        return seqNo;
    }
    public void setSeqNo(int seqNo) {
        this.seqNo = seqNo;
    }
    public char getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(char data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Packet(String type, int seqNo, char data)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.seqNo = seqNo;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Packet()
    {
        this.type = "";
        this.seqNo = 0;
        this.data = ' ';
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Packet: \tType: " + this.type + "\tseqNo: " + this.seqNo + "\tdata: " + this.data;
    }
}
```

Assume that I send: "abc"
Sender:

```
SENT: Packet:   Type: data  seqNo: 0    data: a
SENT: Packet:   Type: data  seqNo: 1    data: b
SENT: Packet:   Type: data  seqNo: 2    data: c
```

Receiver:

```
RECIEVED: Packet:   Type: data  seqNo: 0    data: a
RECIEVED: Packet:   Type: data  seqNo: 0    data: a
RECIEVED: Packet:   Type: data  seqNo: 0    data: a
```

Problem is that receiver prints three "a". Please help me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug this sort of thing, it helps to use `tcpdump` or similar to track what is actually going on the network:

```
$ tcpdump -i lo port 7777
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:53:20.818460 IP zoo.59305 > zoo.7777: UDP, length 83
19:53:20.822292 IP zoo.59305 > zoo.7777: UDP, length 100
19:53:20.822410 IP zoo.59305 > zoo.7777: UDP, length 117
```

This tells you you're sending the 3 packets you expect, but each packet gets 17 bytes larger than the previous (instead of all being the same size).  Examining your sending code carefully explains this -- you use a single ObjectOutputStream to construct the packets, and you don't reset it between Packet objects, so the first packet sent contains the first Packet object, while the second contains *TWO* packet objects (a copy of the first one, and then the scond one), and the third one contains all three.

On the receiver side, you only decode the first Packet object in the recieved packet and print it, so you print the first one three times...